# Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean error in wamp and lamp but not in xampp

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on Point of sale system built on codeigniter. I get this error "Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean". I have just moved to linux and install lamp. I get the similar error on wamp, at that time i removed wamp and install xampp and it work. now i want to use lamp , every thing is good expect it get this error. I have changed php version but it does not help. i can not change in code because it has been used in hundred of places. currently  i am using php  PHP Version 7.0.27 , Apache/2.4.18, sql version :mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux on x86_64. also why it is working in xampp but give error on wamp and lamp, 
Here is full error

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>   Type: Error
>   Message: Call to a member function `num_rows()` on boolean
>   Filename: `/var/www/html/dev.com/public_html/gspos/app/models/admin/Products_model.php`
>   Line Number: 206
>   Backtrace:
>   File: `/var/www/html/dev.com/public_html/gspos/app/controllers/admin/Products.php`
>   Line: 2053
>   Function: getAllWarehousesWithPQ
>   File: `/var/www/html/dev.com/public_html/gspos/index.php`
>   Line: 302
>   Function: require_once

Comment: show us your code where you are getting the error??

Comment: Your query failed, and you need to figure out why.

Comment: I'll go out on a limb here and say you weren't the one who wrote the code.

Comment: Always make sure or check if the query succeeds before calling other query functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have code smells, but if you can't edit it, maybe check the differences between Xampp config and your new config and begin by check php version.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Help . I just installed Xampp and it solved my problem